# Portal 2 end rooms

Tags: portal-2

I had a question about the ending:

> During the end movie, before the elevator gets to the turret symphony room, there are various flashes of small rooms: turrets guarding a cube, double turrets, and one were turrets seem to be manipulating something organic. A big potato? Some kind of creature? What is it?

[image]

Comment: You know, I had a same kind of question about that sequence:  In the turret singing portion, is the largest turret wearing a crown?

Comment: yes, it's the king turret from one of the movies shown on the elevator walls during the initial chapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely a potato. It's more of a joke like the rooms before.

Dare I spread the rumor mill and say it's an observer from Half Life?

Comment: You can also see a giant turret from the turrets promotional ad

Comment: Kindof looks like it has tentacles though